# How do I validate dates in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I have used a php code to validate two dates.If date 1 = date 2 then return false els true.Below is the code where error is it is always returning false.

```
{
$d1 =$values['DATE'];     //date 1 in dd-mm-yyyy format
$d2 =$values['DATE_OF_LEAVE'];   //date 2 in dd-mm-yyyy format

if(strtotime($d1) != strtotime($d2)) 
{
    return true;  
}

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'alert("Application date and leave date should be different.")';
echo '</script>';

return false; 
}
```

Comment: After return true put exit(); or put rest part in else part. but again you have to put exit(). Or may be the problem that date are same.

Comment: i have two text boxes to accept dates.Where i put dates like 08-05-2015 and 08-05-2015  returns false.but when i put 08-05-2015 and 09-05-2015  returns false which should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set both to a least common denominator with `date()`.

```
if(date('Ymd',strtotime($d1)) != date('Ymd',strtotime($d2)))
```